# Payment Gateway within Magento - Accept payments through Credit Card

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-gateway

I will cut the post short.

I need to accept credit card payment through my Magento Install. Now I thought it should be straight forward where I will get the API from some provider (say Authorize.net) and put in my API details within the admin, but alas.

When I searched, all I find is that people are trying to create Custom Payment Gateways instead of using Magento's own admin. I am new to this and I need help in this.

I will be thankful if you can help me in finding answers for:-

- What is the straight forward way (a tutorial may be) to implement payment gateway on my website
- What is the best payment gateway company
- Do I need to make Custom Payment Gateway?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as my knowledge authorize.net gate way is best payment gateway for magento,because it is already used by so many developers and there is a great community forum to help us.So as my suggestion better to use authorize.net.

coming to integration method you,use authorize.net**AMI** method.  In Magento Admin `System->Configuration->Payment Method` You can see Authorize.net payment Method in that you can Customize  with your AUthorize.net API Login information.please go through this [authorize.net](http://developer.authorize.net/api/compare/) link for more details.

hope this may help you,thank you very much

Comment: how about Indian payment gateways, will it support.